# Draw a line on a figure with multiple axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a figure with multiple axes and added AnchoredText to some of these axes. This AnchoredText is like a label which connects the axis in which it resides to an outer axis, like this:

[[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj2vD.png)]

I have tried using AnnnotationBbox like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText, AnnotationBbox, TextArea

fig_width = 16
fig_height = 9

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height))

fig.add_axes(
    (0, 0, 1, 1),
    alpha=1,
    xticks=[],
    yticks=[],
)

fig.get_axes()[-1].set_xlim(0, fig_width)
fig.get_axes()[-1].set_ylim(0, fig_height)

fig.add_axes(
    (0.66, 0.225, 0.075, 0.025),
    label="L1",
    alpha=1,
    xticks=[],
    yticks=[],
)

axis = fig.get_axes()[-1]

axis.set_xlim(
    fig_width * 0.66, fig_width * (0.66 + .075)
)
axis.set_ylim(
    fig_height * .225, fig_height * (.225 + .025)
)

circle = AnchoredText(
        s="L1",
        frameon=False,
        loc="upper left",
        prop=dict(bbox=dict(boxstyle="circle")),
    )

axis.add_artist(circle)

fig.add_axes(
    (0.62, 0.28, 0.03, 0.04),
    label="L2",
    alpha=1,
    xticks=[],
    yticks=[],
)

axis = fig.get_axes()[-1]

axis.set_xlim(
    fig_width * 0.62, fig_width * (0.62 + .03)
)
axis.set_ylim(
    fig_height * .28, fig_height * (.28 + .04)
)

def get_axes(fig, name):
    for ax in fig.axes:
        label = ax.get_label()

        if label == name:
            return ax

l1 = get_axes(fig, "L1") # Gets axis with given label
l2 = get_axes(fig, "L2")
offsetbox = TextArea("Test")
    
# Get the top outer limit of the l2 axis
xlim = (l2.get_xlim()[0] + l2.get_xlim()[1]) / 2
ylim = l2.get_ylim()[1]
xy = [xlim, ylim]

# Approximating the coordinates of AnchoredText
xlim2 = l1.get_xlim()[0] * 0.25
ylim2 = l1.get_ylim()[0] * 0.75
xy2 = [xlim2, ylim2]

ab = AnnotationBbox(
   offsetbox,
   xy2,
   xybox=xy,
   xycoords="data",
   boxcoords=("axes fraction", "data"),
   box_alignment=(0.0, 0.5),
   arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
)

l1.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

Running the code above does not add the line in my figure and I'm not sure why. Is there a better way to approach this problem? How can I get the limit of the AnchoredText, if at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is stab at it. The trick is to plot the subplots in one general blank (and transparent) axes and then plot a line connecting the subplots.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

# Initialize figure
fig, ax_canvas = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6), constrained_layout=True)

# Set order of drawing, Ax canvas will be the last one so that the line connecting the other plots is on top
ax_canvas.set_zorder(10)
# Hide the main axis to set our blank canvas
ax_canvas.set_axis_off()
# Make background transparent so that it does not cover other plots when we draw the connecting line
ax_canvas.patch.set_facecolor('None')
ax_canvas.patch.set_visible(False)
# Set dimensions so it's easier to plot the line correctly
ax_canvas.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax_canvas.set_ylim([0, 1])

# First subplot axes in the canvas
left1, bottom1, width1, height1 = [0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4]
ax1 = fig.add_axes([left1, bottom1, width1, height1])
ax1.set_zorder(0)
ax1.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax1.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax1.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Ax 1')

# Add the circle
circle = AnchoredText(
    s="L1",
    frameon=False,
    loc="upper left",
    prop=dict(bbox=dict(boxstyle="circle")),
)
ax1.add_artist(circle)

# Second axes in the canvas
left2, bottom2, width2, height2 = [0.45, 0.15, 0.3, 0.2]
ax2 = fig.add_axes([left2, bottom2, width2, height2])
ax1.set_zorder(0)
ax2.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax2.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Ax 2')

# Line connecting Ax1 and Ax2 in the Ax canvas
# The values below are eyeballed based on the ax_canvas having x and y limits 0 to 1
# Roughly where the circle is in Ax1, x middle of Ax2
x_line = [0.125, 0.6]
# Roughly where the circle is in Ax1, height of Ax2
y_line = [0.87, 0.35]
ax_canvas.plot(x_line, y_line, c='k', ls='--')

plt.show()
```

[image: fig axes]

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using ConnectionPatch, which helped in my case. It would be great if we were able to get coordinates through some method or attribute access instead of having to eyeball (referring to the AnchoredText), which would make for better OOP.